# Update a view in a fragment

Tags: android, view, fragment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ViewPager Activity to notify a Fragment of a specific event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956803/viewpager-activity-to-notify-a-fragment-of-a-specific-event)

I am experimenting with using fragments and I ran into this problem.
I have a service running in the background which I want to update a listview in a fragment. 
First I just wanted to have the fragment listen for a broadcast, but it seems like registerReceiver is not allowed in a fragment?
How do I do this. Do I need to listen for a broadcast in the main activity and then somhow send it to the fragment?

Comment: -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956803/viewpager-activity-to-notify-a-fragment-of-a-specific-event ?

Comment: Booooooo on the part of the moderators trying to shut down a intelligent discussion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the activity for this. Google has some good examples and description of the topic fragment and activity communication. You can read about it here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

In short, fragments use listeners to communicate with activities and activities just use public methodes in fragments.

Comment: Well, that was easy :) Thank you.