# Android Refreshing Fragment View after AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, fragment

I am trying to update list fragment when an `AsyncTask` in my activity completes but I am not sure if I am doing something wrong. Currently, I have a button that initiates the `AsyncTask`:

```
search = (Button)findViewById(R.id.search);
    search.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String productname = prodname.getText().toString().trim();
                    if (NetworkManager.isOnline(getApplicationContext())){
                        // Go to Other screen
                        AsyncFetcher results = new AsyncFetcher(currActivity);
                        String _url = "http://192.168.1.3:3000/search.json?
                                       utf8=%E2%9C%93&q="+productname;
                        // progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(
                        //    ClassifiedsActivity.this, "", "Loading...");
                        results.execute(_url);
                    } else {
                        // Throw some warning saying no internet 
                        // connection was found
                    }
                }
            });
```

Once my execute is finished I have following to instantiate fragment within my activity:

```
ResultFragment resultfrag = new ResultFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                           .replace(R.id.content_frame, resultfrag).commit();
```

However it doesnt seem to replace my content with the list fragment.
Here is my layout file:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First replacing a fragment is nothing like refreshing it. Yes, it reloads every view in it and data as well. But you have to relate it with your new data. So i would recomment you to create a refresh method in your fragment and send this method your refreshed data, then notify your adapter as `dataSetChanged`.

To achieve this, you're gonna need to reach your currently attached fragment and call its refresh method. You can use `findFragmentByTag` to reach it out.

**Edit: To clarify little bit more**

When your `AsyncTask` is done, you should do something like this `onPostExecute` method:

```
ResultFragment resultFrag = (ResultFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                                 .findFragmentByTag("FragToRefresh");
if (resultFrag != null) {
    resultFrag.refreshData(refreshedArray);
}
```

And in your `ResultFragment` you need to have `refreshData` method, which is something like this:

```
public void refreshData(ArrayList<YourObject> data) {
   yourArray = new ArrayList<YourObject>(data);
   yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And your list will be refreshed whenever your task is done.

Comment: Hi yahya, thank you for response. I added the methods you described here and also had to add "m_adapter.clear();
  m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  m_adapter.addAll(this.search_results);" to make the refresh data work since the adapter was still holding reference to the old "ArrayList".

Comment: Ahh yes, it of course depends on how you handle with listView and its adapter. I'm glad that you did it :)