# How to refresh next and previous Fragment view in view pager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

What i am doing is showing Fragment in view pager and has Gesture detector implemented on Whole view. When we touch the View i want to hide some layouts from current fragment and all other fragments in view pager.

But problem is this that view pager automatically generates next and previous view 
and when i swipe to next view it does not hide those layouts but other Fragments other than its consecutive ones Layouts are Gone.

How do i refresh consecutive fragments of view pager from fragment itself.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should have an activity that control that `ViewPager` and detects what Fragments to display. That's the place to update the fragments.

Use the `OnPageChangeListener` listener and inform the fragment of the change.

If you want to do it from the Fragment itself, try `onStart()` or `onResume()`

Answer (score 0):

Fragments can be notified of events, so they can take actions accordingly.

One way of doing this would be using a broadcast like in [ViewPager Activity to notify a Fragment of a specific event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956803/viewpager-activity-to-notify-a-fragment-of-a-specific-event)

Other way is like @Antonio said, making it on the OnPageChangeListener (I suppose that would be a lot cleaner).

Comment: i am using OnPageChangeListener like this and calling fragment method to change the visibility of Views but it gives NPE

@Override
   public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
    Fragment frag = adapter.getItem(arg0);
    ((PageFragment) frag).changeVisibility(MainActivity.this);
   }

Comment: Where does it throw NPE? I mean, which of those is null?

Comment: Layouts that i want to hide

commonData = (CommonData) context.getApplication();
  if (commonData.isViewHidden) {
   bottomRL.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   actionBarRL.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  } else {
   bottomRL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   actionBarRL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  }

bottomRL and actionBarRL are null

Comment: well, you might have another issue there. Can you edit your post with a more in depth example with code?